# How change the default UTF-8 encoding to LATIN1

Tags: r, xpath, encoding, utf-8, latin1

First time caller.
I just want to change string encoding from UTF-8 to LATIN1. I use Xpath to retrieve the data from the web:

```
>library(RCurl)  
>library(rvest)
>library(XML)
>library(httr)
>library(reshape2)
>library(reshape)

>response <- GET(paste0("http://www.visalietuva.lt/imone/jogminda-uab-telsiai-muziejaus-g-35"))
>doc <- content(response,type="text/html")
>base <- xpathSApply(doc, "//ul//li//span",xmlValue)[5]
```

As as result I get the following:

```
>base
[1] "El. paÅ¡tas"
```

When I check the encoding I have UTF-8:

```
>Encoding(base)
[1] "UTF-8"
```

I suspect I need LATIN1 encoding. So that the result would be **"El. paštas"**, instead of **"El. paÅ¡tas"**.

Although when I specifie the LATIN1 encoding I get the following:

```
>latin <- iconv(base, from = "UTF-8", to = "LATIN1")
[1] "El. paÅ¡tas"
```

i.e. the same result as with UTF-8. Changing the encoding does not help to get **"El. paštas"**.

Moreover I need the correct LATIN1 encoding of the string while saving data to .csv file. I tried to save the data to .csv:

```
write.table(latin,file = "test.csv")
```

and get the same strange characters as mentioned above: **"El. paÅ¡tas"**.

Any advice on how to change the encoding would be more than welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
doc <- content(response,type="text/html", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Thank you. That answers first part of the question. Now I can read data from url using correct encoding. Although are there any solutions to read the data from csv, when it contains such characters?
Let assume that I have file with these strange symbols and I would like to read it into R with correct encoding as mentioned before (use UTF-8). I assume it won't work:
file = read.csv("strangedata.csv", header=F, stringsAsFactors = F,encoding = "UTF-8")

Comment: Well, why don't you just  try `write.table` and `read.table` before assuming something? ;-) The help file `?read.csv` has a section on encoding.

Comment: I do tried these recommendations but fail to get the result. The code is above:

# utf.csv sample data link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l77javsoy1272v8/utf.csv?dl=1

# reading strange characters from .csv
read <- read.csv("utf.csv", 
                   encoding = "UTF-8", 
                   header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# writing to .csv with UTF-8
con <- file("write.csv", open="w", encoding="UTF-8")
write.table(read, con, sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
close(con)

Still, some characters in write.csv are strange.

Comment: You should post a new question using refering to your sample data. Encoding errors is like opening Pandora's box...